# Py4JJava error on pyspark on azure databrick platform

Tags: postgresql, azure, pyspark, databricks

I need to execute postgressql in pyspark
I tried following:-

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("ReadFromPostgreSQL").getOrCreate()

url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database_example"

properties = {"user": "postgres", "password": "1234", "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver"}

query = "SELECT * FROM arpan.check_master_planning_family"

jdbcDF = spark.read.jdbc(url=url, table=query, properties=properties)
```

Here I have replace username, password and url with my server url, username and password.

But I received this error:-

```
Py4JJavaError:-org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"
```

This query run perfectly in postgres but here I m getting error. Please Solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `table=query` to `table="<table_name>"`

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("ReadFromPostgreSQL").getOrCreate()

url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database_example"
properties = {"user": "postgres", "password": "1234", "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver"}

employee_df = spark.read.jdbc(url=url, table="employee", properties=properties)
department_df = spark.read.jdbc(url=url, table="department", properties=properties)
```

**1. Using DataFrame**

```
employee_df.join(department_df, employee_df.dept_id == department_df.id, "inner").show()
```

**2. Using Spark SQL**

Create a temp view out of this DataFrame

```
employee_df.createOrReplaceTempView("employee")
department_df.createOrReplaceTempView("department")
```

Now use `spark.sql` to write a code in SQL format:

```
spark.sql('''
    SELECT * FROM employee AS emp
    JOIN department AS dept
    ON emp.dept_id = dept.id
''').show()
```

Comment: It work but if i have to use two table for joining how should I do it?